# Custom module is not working

Tags: routes

I created custom module to display `Hello world` text in custom page. I did not install **drush** and **composer** in my windows machine as I don't have admin access. I have pasted my files below:

**example.module**

```
<?php

function example_menu() 
{
  // The paths given here need to match the ones in example.routing.yml exactly.
  $items['/mypage/page'] = array(
    'title' => 'First page',
    'description' => 'This is a example page.',
    // The name of the route from example.routing.yml
    'route' => 'example.my_page',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

**example.routing**

```
example.my_page:
  path: '/mypage/page'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::mypage'
    _title: 'Hello world'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**src/Controller/ExampleController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Controller;

//use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class ExampleController 
{
    public function myPage() 
    {
        $element = array('#markup' => 'Hello world!');
        return $element;
    }
}
```

And I have **example.info** file as well and the module is enabled. When I run the controller, it says `page not found`. Can anyone tell me that Am I missed anything in the code?

Comment: Drupal 8 has no hook_menu(), so you can definitely remove that. could be the difference between myPage and mypage, yes.

Comment: @Berdir, array $items value of 'route' => 'example.my_page' is correct? or it should say 'route' => 'example.mypage'? in example.module file

Comment: It doesn't matter because hook_menu no longer exists. That code will do nothing.

Comment: Then how it should be?

Comment: Should drush and composer have installed to run the custom module?

Comment: Those don't matter... like Berdir said it could be a case problem in your routing item. Change it to myPage so it matches the method name, clear the caches and try again. Also, any reason you are not extending ControllerBase?

Comment: I don't want to extend anything from ControllerBase. So, I removed those two lines from the controller. Is it mandatory to extend from the ControllerBase?

Answer (score -2):

`hook_menu` doesn't exist anymore in D8.
Instead use a **example.links.menu.yml** file.

```
example.my_page:
  title: 'First page'
  description: 'yout description'
  route_name: example.my_page
```